# Is there any popup editor function in iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'd like to popup a simple dialog with an editor box, to let user enter some value then just return. I am wondering whether iPhone SDK has that kind of support.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution at :
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html

Here is the code which works for me.

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title here" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];

CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 130.0);
[myAlertView setTransform:myTransform];

[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create your popup (UIAlertView) and add a UITextField (or whatever component you'd like to use) to it as a sub-view.  The UIAlertView won't auto-resize for the component you add so you have to hack that part of it together by adding text to it.  The text will increase the height of your popup and provided you don't add too much be hidden by your component.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to your code it is called before the Alert is displayed.

- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
  alertView.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, width, heigth );
  }

Answer (score 1):

A tip for resizing your UIAlertView...

As Milen Milkovski wrote above/below, if you set a delegate for the UIAlertView:

```
UIAlertView* theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Lah"
                                                   message:@"dee dah"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
//NSLog(@"Pre Show: alert frame x,y: %f,%f, alert frame width,height: %f,%f",  theAlert.frame.origin.x,theAlert.frame.origin.y, theAlert.frame.size.width, theAlert.frame.size.height);
[retrievingListAlert show];
```

You can then modify the frame of the UIAlertView by defining the following UIAlertView callback (in the delegate class- in this case since we used self, the same class as where the UIAlertView was created):

```
(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    //NSLog(@"willPresentAlertView: alert frame midx,midy: %f,%f, alert frame width,height: %f,%f",  alertView.frame.origin.x, alertView.frame.origin.y, alertView.frame.size.width, alertView.frame.size.height);
    alertView.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, width, heigth ); 
}
```

I've found that setting the frame at other times will not work. It appears the show function modifies the frame, presumably while autosizing to it's contents.